# not able to inject DAO in spring bean

Tags: java, spring

In spring 3.o, I am trying to inject my DAO layer object to my singleTon bean using :

```
ApplicationContext applicaionContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(ApplicationConstants.APP_PROPERTY_CONFIG_PATH);

        TemplateManagementDAO  templateManagementDAO =(TemplateManagementDAO) applicaionContext.getBean("templateManagementDAO");
```

But it gives the exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:983)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5364)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:704)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1649)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1254)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.WebModuleDeployEventListener.moduleDeployed(WebModuleDeployEventListener.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.WebModuleDeployEventListener.moduleDeployed(WebModuleDeployEventListener.java:278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.invokeModuleDeployEventListener(AdminEventMulticaster.java:1005)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.handleModuleDeployEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:992)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.processEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:470)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.DeploymentNotificationHelper.multicastEvent(DeploymentNotificationHelper.java:308)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentServiceUtils.multicastEvent(DeploymentServiceUtils.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ServerDeploymentTarget.sendStartEvent(ServerDeploymentTarget.java:298)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ApplicationStartPhase.runPhase(ApplicationStartPhase.java:132)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentPhase.executePhase(DeploymentPhase.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.executePhases(PEDeploymentService.java:966)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.start(PEDeploymentService.java:609)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.start(PEDeploymentService.java:653)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.mbeans.ApplicationsConfigMBean.start(ApplicationsConfigMBean.java:773)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:390)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:373)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.config.BaseConfigMBean.invoke(BaseConfigMBean.java:477)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.proxy.ProxyClass.invoke(ProxyClass.java:90)
    at $Proxy1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.SunoneInterceptor.invoke(SunoneInterceptor.java:304)
    at com.sun.enterprise.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.callers.InvokeCaller.call(InvokeCaller.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.MBeanServerRequestHandler.handle(MBeanServerRequestHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.servlet.RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.processRequest(RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.java:122)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.servlet.RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.doPost(RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.java:193)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:666)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:872)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.WorkerThreadImpl.run(WorkerThreadImpl.java:117)
```

Can anyone suggest me why is is not able to acces DAO object into the bean layer ??
Thanks,
Gunjan Shah.

Comment: BTW, what you are doing is not injecting. You are looking something up, that's called the "Service Locator" pattern, as opposed to Spring's standard modus operandi, which is called either "Dependency Injection" or "Inversion of Control".

Comment: You are most likely missing spring jars on your classpath. Look at your exception again: `NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException`

Answer (score 3):

In your `application-context.xml` define:

```
<bean id="templateManagementDAO" class="yourPackage.TemplateManagementDAO" />
```

Note `TemplateManagementDAO` should the be the implementation class not the interface.

Comment: I have used ths same syntex..but while injection I am getting templateManagementDAO as null. Its working when I used lazy-init="true" option.

Comment: I can only think your design is causing this. If you build your beans once and access many then potential future access will not be able to obtain memory reference of the bean, and therefore you'll have to use the lazy-init to force Spring IOC only to load the bean upon request. Again it looks as if the snippet of code you've above is not all it take to build your bean. There might be some handling eslewhere causing the NPE.

Comment: Let me give u design in more depth..I have used three packages services,dao, and beans. I am scanning service and dao layer with component:scan syntex. Now In service layer there is a bean which is injecting one dao from DAO layer. All the classes in the service layer are annotated with @ service and all the DAOs in DAO layer are annotated with @Repository annotation.

Comment: And here is the xml configuration for injection DAO inside service..
 <bean id="templateManagementDAO" class="com.eks.sel.dao.TemplateManagementDAO">
 </bean>
 <bean id="dynamicAttributeDAO" class="com.eks.sel.dao.DynamicAttributeDAO">
 </bean> 
 <bean id="selStartUpDataInitializer" class="com.eks.sel.service.SELStartUpDataInitializer" factory-method="getInstance">
  <property name="templateManagementDAO" ref="templateManagementDAO" />
  <property name="dynamicAttributeDAO" ref="dynamicAttributeDAO" />
 </bean>

Comment: Your bean defintions looks pretty good to me, although I will suggest you stick with strict annotations - since your design adapt it. And scall all neccesary package to injection your beans using `@Autowired`. If you're getting NULL from your `templateManagementDAO` injection, a) check the class `TemplateManagementDAO` has a constructor and b)Check the way `ApplicationContext` is created to make sure you're doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix this exception first

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException`

which is nothing to do with any Spring config errors. Do you have an old version of Spring on the classpath?

Comment: I have used org.springframework.bean - 3.0.5-RELEASE.jar file

Comment: Yeah, but are there other spring jars hanging around?

Comment: yes... remaining all jars are related to spring 3. But it works when I set lazy-init = true in bean declaration

Comment: How are you doing the deployment? Are you using Maven? If so please update with the relevant section of the POM.

Comment: No I have not used maven.. Its automatically deployed in Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

In your Spring Context configuration file, if you've activated package scanning to discover beans based on annotations (), you can just annotate your DAO class with @Repository as well.

Comment: DAOs are already annotated with @Repository annotation. Still it gives the same error

Comment: Given the type of error you're getting, maybe you could try running your application in debug mode and setting a breakpoint where Spring tries to instantiate the missing class. Then, it will pinpoint which class definition is missing and by the same way, you'll see which jar you're missing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception. It gives not much information. By doing a lot of debugging I found out I was getting a stack overflow exception when instantiating a bean. It was given by and endless recursive call between 2 factory methods annotated with @Bean.

This is the stack trace before it dies, maybe it was happening the same to you and the @Lazy annotation helped to avoid this...

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x09151000 nid=0x4c10 runnable [0xf733b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig.fileRouters(ElephantConfig.java:276)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7.CGLIB$fileRouters$14(<generated>)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1e5bbc2f.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7.fileRouters(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        - locked <0xe04f0fb8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:292)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7.fileRouters(<generated>)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig.faultToleranceArbiter(ElephantConfig.java:302)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7.CGLIB$faultToleranceArbiter$15(<generated>)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1e5bbc2f.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7.faultToleranceArbiter(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        - locked <0xe04f0fb8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:292)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7.faultToleranceArbiter(<generated>)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig.fileRouters(ElephantConfig.java:292)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7.CGLIB$fileRouters$14(<generated>)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1e5bbc2f.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7.fileRouters(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        - locked <0xe04f0fb8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:292)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7.fileRouters(<generated>)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig.writersRunners(ElephantConfig.java:256)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7.CGLIB$writersRunners$13(<generated>)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1e5bbc2f.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.config.ElephantConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b38541f7.writersRunners(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        - locked <0xe04f0fb8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        - locked <0xe04f0fb8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        - locked <0xe04f0fb8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        - locked <0xe04f1df0> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        - locked <0xe04f1eb0> (a java.lang.Object)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.launch.Launcher.createSpringContext(Launcher.java:109)
        at com.cme.datamine.elephant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:55)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Facundo. The problem was generated bcoz controllers were accessing the DAO before its completely scanned. It works fine after  setting  lazy-init = true option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was generated because my application intializer class trying the access the DAOs before its get loaded by the container.

So after using lazy-init = true option it works fine.

```
  <!-- LAZY LOAD THIS BEAN TO RESOLVE DAO INJECTION PROBLEM INTO THE BEAN -->
    <bean id="selStartUpDataInitializer" class="com.eks.sel.service.SELStartUpDataInitializer"
        factory-method="getInstance" lazy-init="true">
    </bean>
```

For your further reference, And here is the class where I have used DAOs from where the exception getting generated..

```
public class SELStartUpDataInitializer  implements Cloneable{

    private static SELStartUpDataInitializer selStartUpDataInitializer;
    private static final Logger LOGGER =Logger.getLogger(SELStartUpDataInitializer.class);
    private static Map<String,Object> staticContextMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 


    //PRIVATE CONSTRUCTOR : FOR SINGLE TON
    private SELStartUpDataInitializer(){                
        initializeTempalteDataFieldMap();
    }

    //OVERRIDE CLONNABLE METHOD
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        if(selStartUpDataInitializer==null){
            selStartUpDataInitializer = new SELStartUpDataInitializer();
        }
        return selStartUpDataInitializer;
    }


    //GET INSTANCE : USED BY BEAN TO INITIALIZE THE BEAN 
    public static synchronized SELStartUpDataInitializer getInstance(){
        if(selStartUpDataInitializer==null){
            selStartUpDataInitializer = new SELStartUpDataInitializer();
        }
        return selStartUpDataInitializer;
    }   



    //INITIALIZE TEMPALTE DATA FILEDs : CALLED BY ONE TIME CONSTRUCTOR
    public  void initializeTempalteDataFieldMap(){      
        LOGGER.info("SELStartUPDataInitializer ... Initializing all temaplte data mapping fields ....");
        Map<Integer, Map<String,String>> templateDatafieldMap = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String,String>>();
        LOGGER.info("Loading application contex from the class path : STARTED");
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(ApplicationConstants.APP_RELOAD_PROPERTY_CONFIG_PATH);
        LOGGER.info("Loading application contex from the class path : COMPLETED");
        //ITS MANDATORY TO CAST BY INTERFACE. OTHERWISE $PROXY ERROR WILL BE GENERATED
        ITemplateManagementDAO  templateManagementDAO =(ITemplateManagementDAO) applicationContext.getBean("templateManagementDAO");                

        List<Template> templates = templateManagementDAO.findByStatus(1);
        LOGGER.info("initializeDataFields, number of templates = "+templates.size());

        for (Template template : templates) {
            String base64TffFile = ApplicationConstants.BASE64_PREFIX + 
                            new String(Base64.encodeBase64(template.getTemplateFile().getBytes()));

            LOGGER.info("initializeDataFields, initializing templateId = "+template.getTemplateid()+".");
            templateDatafieldMap.put(template.getTemplateid(), SELUtil.getDatafieldNames(base64TffFile));
            LOGGER.info("initializeDataFields, templateId = "+template.getTemplateid()+" initialized.");
        }

        IDynamicAttributeDAO dynamicAttributeDAO =(IDynamicAttributeDAO) applicationContext.getBean("dynamicAttributeDAO");

        staticContextMap.put(ApplicationConstants.TEMPLATE_DATAFIELD_MAP, templateDatafieldMap);
        staticContextMap.put(ApplicationConstants.ECC5_SAPTODATAFIELD_MAP,dynamicAttributeDAO.getAllSAPtoDataFieldAttribsMap(SAPConstants.SAP_ECC5));
        staticContextMap.put(ApplicationConstants.ECC6_SAPTODATAFIELD_MAP,dynamicAttributeDAO.getAllSAPtoDataFieldAttribsMap(SAPConstants.SAP_ECC6));
        staticContextMap.put(ApplicationConstants.ALL_DYNAMICATTRIBS_MAP,dynamicAttributeDAO.getAllDynamicAttributesMap());

    }


    public  Map<String, Object> getStaticContextMap() {
        return staticContextMap;
    }



}
```

In above class, I was trying the reload / rescan the beans using ClassPathXMLApplicationContext. So here the exception  was generated while using DAOs.

It was trying the retrieve the DAOs before the configuration is totally scanned  and all the beans are intialized.